# Not able to connect using websocket.Getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to use web socket to fetch data from a site. Here is my code

```
         var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
         var client = new WebSocketClient();
          client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
          console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
          });

          client.on('connect', function(connection) {
          console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
          connection.on('error', function(error) {
              console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
          });
         connection.on('close', function() {
           console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
         });
          connection.on('message', function(message) {

           console.log("Received: '" + message + "'");

         });

        function sendNumber() {
            if (connection.connected) {
                 connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({
                    key: 'Anisha$Hi'
                    }));
              } 
        }
         sendNumber();
      });



     client.connect('wss://sarthak999.pythonanywhere.com/', 'echo-protocol');
```

But I'm getting connection error addrnotfound.what is the problem?I want to fetch some data from the URL.This is the error i'm getting :

```
      Connect Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sarthak999.pythonanywhere.com sarthak999.pythonanywhere.com:443
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to a pythonanywhere webapp over wss (it is not supported).